# Salesforce event monitoring log access required permissions

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, event, debug-logs, eventlogfile

Have a requirement to create a permission set which will allow users to access the event log monitoring files. As per this link https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000363350&type=1 User's need the API Enabled system permission and the View Event Log Files permission.

When testing the user's have the API Enabled permission on their profile and the View Event Log Files permission on the new permission set. Despite this they still are unable to access these logs. Is there some additional permission required which is not outlined in the documentation? - Thank in advance!

Comment: Are these users able to see all the event types?

Comment: _Despite this they still are unable to access these logs_ - please provide additional detail on this, a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Issue was that when using the 'login As' functionality access to the event logs was not working. Worked fine when logging in with username and password